# Dynamically resize div for background image

Tags: css, background-image, image-resizing

I have a background image in a header that automatically resizes to the width of the window. However, the height does not adjust properly -- an inherited CSS property sets the div to a fixed height of 50px.

Currently, I'm using:

```
background-size: cover;
```

I can specify a fixed height for the div that will be observed, but then the background is only correct at a specific window size. If I set the size to auto or 100%, it goes to 50px; How can I make it ignore the height it thinks it should be and just autoresize the header div to a background image that adjusts to window size?

Comment: Mind sharing some more code, HTML, CSS...?

Comment: This is a ruby on rails app where the code, css, etc even for just the stuff in this div is scattered across a number of files. I tried to keep the info minimal so that the question is readable, but I agree it's easier to help when context is provided.

As it turns out, there is no way to resize the div to the bg image using styling. Rather, the image needs to be placed in the div and pushed back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div will not expand to accommodate the background image. If you always want to show the full image and have it expand with the div, you can sort of fake the background by using an image tag and some sneaky positioning instead.

```css
img.header-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div.header-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

div.header-contents {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <img class="header-image" alt="Cat Background" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR39_wPEnBeSEOiHXW1Lc0rwqhEVktULcqnvDDA4J-DZL0gndic" />
    <div class="header-contents">Here are some header contents.</div>
</div>
<div class="body-contents">And some regular content.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have tried to use a specific size like this ?

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: That method resulted in something where the width resized correctly, and the height stayed fixed rather than resizing to preserve aspect ratio.